# How can I generate list of classes in order of dependency?

Tags: java, oracle, ant, plsql, dependencies

I'm doing a build script for a Java application to run inside the Oracle JVM. In order to import the 50-odd classes, it appears I need to bring them in in order, so any dependencies are present before compilation.

For each class, I'm running '`create or replace and compile java source {className} as {classPath}`' for each file. Doing this gives me a compilation error, as the required class(es) are not imported.

How can I generate a list of the classes, in dependency order - that is, as you go down the list, the class's dependencies are listed above. I would prefer to do this as an Ant task.

Also if you have a better idea of how to get these classes imported, I'd love to hear your ideas.

Comment: As a bit of a hack, after all the compilation errors,I tried running `ALTER JAVA CLASS "/d6c58067_JdbcPayslipDao" RESOLVE;` for each the 26 invalid classes. This doesn't work, still complaining of compilation errors.

Comment: do you only care about static dependencies or do you also need to know about things like Class.forName("Foo")?

Comment: Just static dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Compile the classes in the filesystem using the [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) task [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html). Use the task [depend](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) if more rigorous dependency checking is needed. Use the [loadjava](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/cheleven.htm#CACFHDJE) tool to load the `.class` and `.java` files into the database in arbitrary order.

Comment: Looking at `dbms_java.loadjava()` currently.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why you'd need to do this, but if you really need to do this, I wonder if hacking a little classloader that prints out each class as it loads and load your app from there would give you a dependency graph?

Comment: It should be noted that dependencies in Java may be cyclic. There isn't really an order which would work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to import the 50-odd classes, it appears I need to bring them in in order so any dependencies are present before compilation.

I have never had to do such a thing simply to compile Java.

This is what Ant was born for.  I'd recommend just doing this with Ant.  Set the <classpath> and you'll have no trouble.

Comment: You're right, in the world of Java or Ant, but this is loading Java classes into Oracle via SQLPlus. 
I'm using Ant to build the deployent artefact and dynamically make the SQL to load the class (ie create...)

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method: put the 50 CREATEs in a batch file and execute it until no errors are found. Create the loop in a shell script. Of course it will never end if there are errors in the sources, but I'm assuming they are ok.

Comment: I don't think the customer would approve of that. 
They've put pretty strict practices in place so far & seem to favouring me manually analysing the classes to generate a list of the classes in order.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not load in a jar file?  Why does it have to be individual classes?